# SVG not visible if used as sprite inside <use> and <symbol>

Tags: svg

The following SVG:

```
<svg
    width="16"
    height="16"
    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
    <rect width="16" height="16" fill="white" />
    <g filter="url(#filter0_d_28_3)">
        <path
            d="M10 6C10 7.10457 9.10457 8 8 8C6.89543 8 6 7.10457 6 6C6 4.89543 6.89543 4 8 4C9.10457 4 10 4.89543 10 6Z"
            fill="url(#paint0_linear_28_3)"
        />
    </g>
    <g filter="url(#filter1_d_28_3)">
        <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M4.14611 7.09306C4.31786 6.9506 4.57258 6.97435 4.71504 7.14611L7.97539 11.077L11.2869 7.14382C11.4306 6.97312 11.6855 6.95125 11.8562 7.09497C12.0269 7.23869 12.0488 7.49358 11.905 7.66428L7.97074 12.3372L4.09306 7.66199C3.9506 7.49024 3.97435 7.23552 4.14611 7.09306Z"
            fill="url(#paint1_linear_28_3)"
        />
    </g>
    <g filter="url(#filter2_d_28_3)">
        <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M13.0162 4.68033L8.15242 1.87223C8.0581 1.81777 7.9419 1.81777 7.84758 1.87223L2.9838 4.68033C2.88949 4.73478 2.83138 4.83542 2.83138 4.94433V10.5605C2.83138 10.6694 2.88949 10.7701 2.9838 10.8245L7.84758 13.6326C7.9419 13.6871 8.0581 13.6871 8.15242 13.6326L13.0162 10.8245C13.1105 10.7701 13.1686 10.6694 13.1686 10.5605V4.94433C13.1686 4.83542 13.1105 4.73478 13.0162 4.68033ZM8.56811 1.15223C8.21656 0.949258 7.78344 0.949258 7.43189 1.15223L2.56811 3.96033C2.21656 4.16329 2 4.53839 2 4.94433V10.5605C2 10.9665 2.21656 11.3416 2.56811 11.5445L7.43189 14.3526C7.78344 14.5556 8.21656 14.5556 8.56811 14.3526L13.4319 11.5445C13.7834 11.3416 14 10.9665 14 10.5605V4.94433C14 4.53839 13.7834 4.16329 13.4319 3.96033L8.56811 1.15223Z"
            fill="url(#paint2_linear_28_3)"
        />
    </g>
    <defs>
        <filter
            id="filter0_d_28_3"
            x="5.8"
            y="3.8"
            width="4.4"
            height="4.4"
            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
        >
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
            <feColorMatrix
                in="SourceAlpha"
                type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                result="hardAlpha"
            />
            <feOffset />
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.1" />
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out" />
            <feColorMatrix
                type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"
            />
            <feBlend
                mode="normal"
                in2="BackgroundImageFix"
                result="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
            />
            <feBlend
                mode="normal"
                in="SourceGraphic"
                in2="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                result="shape"
            />
        </filter>
        <filter
            id="filter1_d_28_3"
            x="3.8"
            y="6.8"
            width="8.4"
            height="5.73716"
            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
        >
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
            <feColorMatrix
                in="SourceAlpha"
                type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                result="hardAlpha"
            />
            <feOffset />
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.1" />
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out" />
            <feColorMatrix
                type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"
            />
            <feBlend
                mode="normal"
                in2="BackgroundImageFix"
                result="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
            />
            <feBlend
                mode="normal"
                in="SourceGraphic"
                in2="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                result="shape"
            />
        </filter>
        <filter
            id="filter2_d_28_3"
            x="1.8"
            y="0.8"
            width="12.4"
            height="13.9049"
            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
        >
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
            <feColorMatrix
                in="SourceAlpha"
                type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                result="hardAlpha"
            />
            <feOffset />
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.1" />
            <feColorMatrix
                type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"
            />
            <feBlend
                mode="normal"
                in2="BackgroundImageFix"
                result="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
            />
            <feBlend
                mode="normal"
                in="SourceGraphic"
                in2="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                result="shape"
            />
        </filter>
        <linearGradient
            id="paint0_linear_28_3"
            x1="8"
            y1="3.55556"
            x2="8"
            y2="8.48148"
            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
            <stop stop-color="#C5F8ED" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#25B18E" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
            id="paint1_linear_28_3"
            x1="8"
            y1="7.40405"
            x2="8"
            y2="11.7071"
            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
            <stop stop-color="#C6F8EE" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#24B18E" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
            id="paint2_linear_28_3"
            x1="8"
            y1="0.824225"
            x2="8"
            y2="14.6806"
            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
            <stop stop-color="#C6F8EE" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#24B18E" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Shows up correctly, but not if used like this:

```
<svg class="inline self-center h-20 w-20 bg-red-500">
    <use href="/build/_assets/sprite-URSEH3F7.svg#logo"></use>
</svg>
```

Content of `/build/_assets/sprite-URSEH3F7.svg`:

```
<svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            width="0"
            height="0"
        >
            <defs>
                <symbol viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" id="logo">
                    <rect width="16" height="16" fill="white" />
                    <g filter="url(#filter0_d_28_3)">
                        <path
                            d="M10 6C10 7.10457 9.10457 8 8 8C6.89543 8 6 7.10457 6 6C6 4.89543 6.89543 4 8 4C9.10457 4 10 4.89543 10 6Z"
                            fill="url(#paint0_linear_28_3)"
                        />
                    </g>
                    <g filter="url(#filter1_d_28_3)">
                        <path
                            fill-rule="evenodd"
                            clip-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M4.14611 7.09306C4.31786 6.9506 4.57258 6.97435 4.71504 7.14611L7.97539 11.077L11.2869 7.14382C11.4306 6.97312 11.6855 6.95125 11.8562 7.09497C12.0269 7.23869 12.0488 7.49358 11.905 7.66428L7.97074 12.3372L4.09306 7.66199C3.9506 7.49024 3.97435 7.23552 4.14611 7.09306Z"
                            fill="url(#paint1_linear_28_3)"
                        />
                    </g>
                    <g filter="url(#filter2_d_28_3)">
                        <path
                            fill-rule="evenodd"
                            clip-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M13.0162 4.68033L8.15242 1.87223C8.0581 1.81777 7.9419 1.81777 7.84758 1.87223L2.9838 4.68033C2.88949 4.73478 2.83138 4.83542 2.83138 4.94433V10.5605C2.83138 10.6694 2.88949 10.7701 2.9838 10.8245L7.84758 13.6326C7.9419 13.6871 8.0581 13.6871 8.15242 13.6326L13.0162 10.8245C13.1105 10.7701 13.1686 10.6694 13.1686 10.5605V4.94433C13.1686 4.83542 13.1105 4.73478 13.0162 4.68033ZM8.56811 1.15223C8.21656 0.949258 7.78344 0.949258 7.43189 1.15223L2.56811 3.96033C2.21656 4.16329 2 4.53839 2 4.94433V10.5605C2 10.9665 2.21656 11.3416 2.56811 11.5445L7.43189 14.3526C7.78344 14.5556 8.21656 14.5556 8.56811 14.3526L13.4319 11.5445C13.7834 11.3416 14 10.9665 14 10.5605V4.94433C14 4.53839 13.7834 4.16329 13.4319 3.96033L8.56811 1.15223Z"
                            fill="url(#paint2_linear_28_3)"
                        />
                    </g>
                    <defs>
                        <filter
                            id="filter0_d_28_3"
                            x="5.8"
                            y="3.8"
                            width="4.4"
                            height="4.4"
                            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
                        >
                            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                            <feColorMatrix
                                in="SourceAlpha"
                                type="matrix"
                                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                                result="hardAlpha"
                            />
                            <feOffset />
                            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.1" />
                            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out" />
                            <feColorMatrix
                                type="matrix"
                                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"
                            />
                            <feBlend
                                mode="normal"
                                in2="BackgroundImageFix"
                                result="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                            />
                            <feBlend
                                mode="normal"
                                in="SourceGraphic"
                                in2="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                                result="shape"
                            />
                        </filter>
                        <filter
                            id="filter1_d_28_3"
                            x="3.8"
                            y="6.8"
                            width="8.4"
                            height="5.73716"
                            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
                        >
                            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                            <feColorMatrix
                                in="SourceAlpha"
                                type="matrix"
                                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                                result="hardAlpha"
                            />
                            <feOffset />
                            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.1" />
                            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out" />
                            <feColorMatrix
                                type="matrix"
                                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"
                            />
                            <feBlend
                                mode="normal"
                                in2="BackgroundImageFix"
                                result="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                            />
                            <feBlend
                                mode="normal"
                                in="SourceGraphic"
                                in2="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                                result="shape"
                            />
                        </filter>
                        <filter
                            id="filter2_d_28_3"
                            x="1.8"
                            y="0.8"
                            width="12.4"
                            height="13.9049"
                            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
                        >
                            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                            <feColorMatrix
                                in="SourceAlpha"
                                type="matrix"
                                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
                                result="hardAlpha"
                            />
                            <feOffset />
                            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.1" />
                            <feColorMatrix
                                type="matrix"
                                values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"
                            />
                            <feBlend
                                mode="normal"
                                in2="BackgroundImageFix"
                                result="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                            />
                            <feBlend
                                mode="normal"
                                in="SourceGraphic"
                                in2="effect1_dropShadow_28_3"
                                result="shape"
                            />
                        </filter>
                        <linearGradient
                            id="paint0_linear_28_3"
                            x1="8"
                            y1="3.55556"
                            x2="8"
                            y2="8.48148"
                            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                        >
                            <stop stop-color="#C5F8ED" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#25B18E" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient
                            id="paint1_linear_28_3"
                            x1="8"
                            y1="7.40405"
                            x2="8"
                            y2="11.7071"
                            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                        >
                            <stop stop-color="#C6F8EE" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#24B18E" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient
                            id="paint2_linear_28_3"
                            x1="8"
                            y1="0.824225"
                            x2="8"
                            y2="14.6806"
                            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                        >
                            <stop stop-color="#C6F8EE" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#24B18E" />
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                </symbol>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

I checked to see if the file URL inside  was correct. It was.

I checked to see if the file it points to contains the `<symbol>` with the correct ID. It does.

I expected the SVG to show up correctly, but it doesn't.

Why is that?

Comment: non-SVGGraphics elements such as filters, gradients etc are not supported in remote use elements by any current browser.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for bringing clarity to this! Do you know if caniuse.com tracks this?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=751733&q=use&can=41035898

Comment: You can build your SVG client-side with a modern Web Component: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76077591/use-a-symbol-with-style-to-apply-css-rules-based-on-classes-applied-to

Comment: Thanks, those are very useful links 

Comment: If you don't need to color your icons dynamically you could also use a [fragment identifier approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77133659/how-do-i-use-the-icon-from-the-svg-sprite-directly-in-the-css-scss/77136312#77136312) and load your svg icons in an `<img>` element.